# Regex for a string of alphabets and spaces

Tags: django

In django's /urls.py file, how to write the regular expression for the string of alphabets and spaces?

For example, `url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results')` matches `/polls/5/results/`

Simlarly I am looking for a regex to match `/polls/Zero%20Dark%20Thirty/results/` or `/polls/Inception/results/`

Answer (score 3):

Use a character class, such as `'[a-zA-Z ]'`